# Why was everything hexagonal?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, wandavision

In *WandaVision*, the hexagonal shape comes up a lot, and there seems to be a specific reason for it, as we can see Jimmy writing it on the board.

[image]

Things that are hexagonal in *WandaVision* include: The shape of the Hex, the intros for the first few episodes, the pattern on Wanda's blanket, etc.

Some of it might be a coincidence, but once they brought it up inside the show as a real mystery, there has to be a reason for it, no?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=thOifuHs6eY

Comment: because Hex = spell? kind of an indication?

Comment: hexagons are the bestagons!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We don't know for sure but we can take a pretty good guess. In the comics Wanda's powers and more specifically her spells are referred to as hexes hex magic. For example, we see this in *Mystic Arcana: Scarlet Witch*:

[image: Wanda celebrates as she is watched by a group discussing her magic including the line: "Truly she will be a force. The way she interrupted all our magics with her first hex..."]
<sub>*Click image to enlarge.*</sub>

Of course hex refers to spells, magic and the supernatural in the real world as well. For example, this definition from the Cambridge Dictionary:

> an evil spell, bringing bad luck and trouble
>
> <sub>[Cambridge Dictionary, hex](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/hex)</sub>

It is likely just because of this: hex being the start of hexagon and hexagonal.

Lastly, it is worth noting that when Tony is analysing the Mind Stone in *Avengers: Age of Ultron* it's structure is shown to be hexagonal in shape. Now Wanda's powers were only brought forward and amplified by the Mind Stone but this could also explain why her magic seems to work in hexagons.

[image: Tony scans the Mind Stone revealing a hexagonal structure]